# I'm having trouble inserting values with using a foreign key in mySQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

I've created tables for customers and orders as follows:

```
mysql> create table customers (
-> customer_id int PRIMARY KEY,
-> lastname varchar(30),
-> firstname varchar(30),
-> address varchar(100),
-> phone_num char(12));

mysql> create table orders (
-> order_id int primary key,
-> date_placed date,
-> delivery_date date,
-> total_cost float,
-> paid boolean,
-> customer_id int,
-> foreign key (customer_id) references orders(customer_id));
```

I've created a customer named Joseph Smith like this:

```
insert into customers values(1, 'Smith', 'Joseph', '1 Grey Street', '800-867-5309');
```

I want to insert an order of Joseph Smith's into the 'orders' table like this:

```
insert into orders values(1, '01-24-1990', '01-26-1990', true, 1);
```

BUT, I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mr3bn/orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`customer_id`))
```

Would love some clarification as to

1. why this doesn't work and
2. how to actually make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're creating a circular reference from `orders` to `orders` instead of creating a reference from `orders` to `customers`.

Change

```
foreign key (customer_id) references orders(customer_id));
```

to

```
foreign key (customer_id) references customers(customer_id));
                                     ^
```

*Actually it strange how mysql allowed you to do that. Mine is failing with the message 'Can't create table 'test.orders' (errno: 150)'*

Besides that in your second insert

1. add a value for `cost` column as @Mortalus said;
2. change format for dates to 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

**Here is working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6bc0/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint is not proper and basically your server should have not permitted you to do it. I am working on SQL Server and i tried your code but it didn't work because of improper constraint it gave me following error

"
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'orders' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_*orders*_custome__4A3B5A08' "

As said by @peterm change your constraint.